# Why doesn't the excess charge on a conducting disk go to its perimeter?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, gauss-law

For 3D conducting objects we know that any excess charge placed inside will go to the boundary, the reason given is that the free charges will move around till they cancel the field inside the conductor and if $E=0$ it means $\rho=0$ hence the excess charge has nowhere except the boundary to go to.

But it we've a charged conducting 2D disk ,the charge doesn't go to the boundary!. However if we apply the same logic as above used for the 3D objects we would end up proving that the excess charge should go to the perimeter of the disk. Which is contradictory. What's wrong here?

Comment: Similar: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/19109/is-it-true-that-vece-neq-0-inside-a-1-or-2-dimensional-conductor

Comment: Do you consider the disc to have an infinitesimal thickness?

Comment: 2D disk, so zero thickness.

Comment: just think of the direction of E in your 2d disk

Answer (score 1):

Consider a 3-D conducting disc with appreciable width. The charges will reside on the surface of this object following say, Gauss Law.

Now keep everything same with charges residing on the surface and start decreasing the width of the disc. The charges will still remain on the surface as they were earlier.

Decrease the width to such an extent that the width tends to zero. Here again the charges will stay put as they were earlier.

What I am saying is that you can think of a disc as a cylinder with infinitesimal small width. In this picture, the charges are actually residing on the surface and not in the infinitesimal small volume.

Get it?